# Ansible: Permission denied (publickey, password)

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm not able to connect to a host in Ansible. This is the error:

> 192.168.1.12 | UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which
>   will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue",
>       "unreachable": true }

This is my `hosts` file:

```
[test]
192.168.1.12
```

And this is the ad-hoc instruction:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

I'm able to connect via raw `ssh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error it returns says it all, the host is unreachable as ssh doesn't work. See what the [ping](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ping_module.html) command does in ansible:

> ping - Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong
>   on success.

If you can do raw ssh, doesn't ensure ansible can. You need to setup key based ssh or add passowrd option:

```
ansible all -m ping --ask-pass
```

> When speaking with remote machines, Ansible by default assumes you are
>   using SSH keys. SSH keys are encouraged but password authentication
>   can also be used where needed by supplying the option `--ask-pass`. If
>   using sudo features and when sudo requires a password, also supply
>   `--ask-sudo-pass`.

Ref:  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html

Comment: Thank you. I have used --ask-pass and --ask-sudo-pass and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing ansible_become=true in the /etc/ansible/hosts file.

Comment: This is hardly a "solution". If you need `become` for your tasks, configure the machines properly so that it works.